# Why would there be a wooden board under cement board in tub alcove?

Tags: bathtub, removal, cement-board

I'm removing the cement board to make tiling easier. I've so far removed two walls.  The third wall however is the one with the shower head and controls on it.

I rubbed away a bit of cement board (to make a hole for a saw), and I noticed this one is different from the other two.  It appears their is a wooden board underneath the cement board.

From what I've read, this isn't normal, and may be detrimental (breath-ability?).  Does anyone know why this may be the case?  Should I remove this board as well, or should I replace it with another board?

Image: [image]

Edit:  I've removed some of the cement board.  No adhesive is between the cement board and the wooden board.

Thanks,
Justin W.

Comment: Pictures would help. One reason to put boards in the walls around a tub is to have some place to anchor grab rails (even when not installing grab rails at first - it's the only time to put that support in there so you have something to screw to if you ever want to add them.) I'm not remotely clear how "removing cement board" (a great tile substrate) is supposed to make tiling easier, either. On the headwall it may be supporting the fixtures.

Comment: I agree cement board makes the best tile backer IMO.

Comment: Maybe replacing is a better word lol.  I am removing it to re-install.  I will post a picture when I can.  I'll also try getting another hole in the wall to check if it's just that one area had a board.  Thanks!

Comment: Ecnerwal, I've added a photo.